# How to groupBy array of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to groupBy my array of an object into some another desired array of objects. I go through several tutorials but didn't get the appropriate output.

What I want is based on their groupBy properties I want to group all the elements

Here is my input

```
permissions= [
    {
      code: 'U00',
      permission_name: 'Read User',
      groupBy: 'User',
      icon: 'user',
    },
    {
      code: 'U01',
      permission_name: 'Create User',
      groupBy: 'User',
      icon: 'user',
    },
  
    {
      code: 'B00',
      permission_name: 'Read Batch',
      groupBy: 'Batch',
      icon: 'user',
    },
    {
      code: 'B01',
      permission_name: 'Create Batch',
      groupBy: 'Batch',
      icon: 'user',
    },
    {
      code: 'B10',
      permission_name: 'Update Batch',
      groupBy: 'Batch',
      icon: 'user',
    },
  ];
```

Required output

```
 Output = [
    {
      label: 'User',
      icon: 'user',
      children: [
        {
          label: 'Create Users',
        },
        {
          label: 'Read All Users',
        },
      
      ],
    },
    {
      label: 'Batch',
      children: [
        {
          label: 'Create Batchs',
        },
        {
          label: 'Read All Batch',
        },
        {
          label: 'Update Batch',
        },
        {
          label: 'Disabled Batch',
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

Comment: What's with the `icon` for `Batch`?

Comment: Group by is a logical equivalent of reduce, so you need a reducer function suiting your needs.

Answer (score 2):

[curItem.groupBy]You should try using `reduce`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```
return Object.values(permissions.reduce((curObj, curItem) => { 
  if(!curObj.hasOwnProperty(curItem.groupBy)){
    curObj[curItem.groupBy] = { 
      label: curItem.label, 
      icon: curItem.icon, 
      children: [] 
    };
  }
  curObj[curItem.groupBy].children.push({ label: curItem.label });
  return curObj;
}, {}));
```

Comment: If  I understand it correctly then pushing should be specified with a `curItem.groupBy` key:


    `curObj[curItem.groupBy].children.push({ label: curItem.permission_name });`

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like:

```js
const output = []

permissions.forEach(obj => {
  const dest = output.find(target => target.label === obj.groupBy);

  if (!dest) {
    output.push({ label: obj.groupBy, icon: obj.icon, children: [ { label: obj.permission_name } ] })
  } else {
    dest.children.push({ label: obj.permission_name })
  }
})
```

You are basically creating a new array, mapping the original based on your requires.

Answer (score 1):

You could first create a function to reduce the array into an object, like so:

```
const groupBy = (prop, list) => {
    return list.reduce((groups, item) => {
        const propVal = item[prop];
        const target = groups[propVal] ?? [];
        
        return { ...groups, [propVal]: [...target, item] };
    }, {});
};
```

Or shorter:

```
const groupBy = (prop, list) => list.reduce((groups, item) => ({ ...groups, [item[prop]]: [...groups[item[prop]] ?? [], item] }), {});
```

And then:

```
const permObj = groupBy('groiupBy', permissions);
// { User: [...], Batch: [...] }
```

Now you could just work with that object or continue by writing a second function:

```
const groupsToArray = (nameProp, groups) => Object.entries(groups).map((g) => ({ [nameProp]: g[0], data: g[1] }))
```

And use it:

```
const newPermList = groupsToArray('label', permObj);
```

which would leave you with an array of objects with the according labels and the children in the 'data' prop of each object.

Of course then you could still filter out or map to get rid of duplicate data that you dont need. But you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You colud find distinct `groupBy` values and then iterate on this array to fill result array like:

```js
let permissions= [
    {
      code: 'U00',
      permission_name: 'Read User',
      groupBy: 'User',
      icon: 'user',
    },
    {
      code: 'U01',
      permission_name: 'Create User',
      groupBy: 'User',
      icon: 'user',
    },
  
    {
      code: 'B00',
      permission_name: 'Read Batch',
      groupBy: 'Batch',
      icon: 'user',
    },
    {
      code: 'B01',
      permission_name: 'Create Batch',
      groupBy: 'Batch',
      icon: 'user',
    },
    {
      code: 'B10',
      permission_name: 'Update Batch',
      groupBy: 'Batch',
      icon: 'user',
    },
  ];
  
  let groups = [...new Set(permissions.map(({groupBy})=>groupBy))];
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++){
     let res = {};
     res.label = groups[i];
     res.icon = permissions.filter(x => x.groupBy === groups[i])[0].icon;
     res.children = [];
     let arrayOfGroup = permissions.filter(x => x.groupBy === groups[i]);
     for (let j = 0; j < arrayOfGroup.length; j ++){
        let child = {};
        child.label = arrayOfGroup[j].permission_name;
        res.children.push(child);
     }
     result.push(res);
  }
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**First step -** get *filtered* necessary `groupBy` values.

**Second step -** mapping through *filtered* `groupBy` values and create a new array of objects based on your requirements.

```js
const permissions = [
  {
    code: 'U00',
    permission_name: 'Read User',
    groupBy: 'User',
    icon: 'user',
  },
  {
    code: 'U01',
    permission_name: 'Create User',
    groupBy: 'User',
    icon: 'user',
  },

  {
    code: 'B00',
    permission_name: 'Read Batch',
    groupBy: 'Batch',
    icon: 'user',
  },
  {
    code: 'B01',
    permission_name: 'Create Batch',
    groupBy: 'Batch',
    icon: 'user',
  },
  {
    code: 'B10',
    permission_name: 'Update Batch',
    groupBy: 'Batch',
    icon: 'user',
  },
];

const groups = [ ...new Set(permissions.map(({ groupBy }) => groupBy)) ];

const result = groups.map(groupName => ({
  value: permissions.find(permission => permission.groupBy === groupName).groupBy,
  icon: permissions.find(permission => permission.icon === groupName.toLowerCase())?.icon,
  children: permissions
    .filter(permission => permission.groupBy === groupName)
    .map(n => ({ value: n.permission_name })),
}));

const output = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)); // For removing undefined keys.

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to alter the `permissions` Array the way you'll like.

```js
let permissions = [{
      code: 'U00',
      permission_name: 'Read User',
      groupBy: 'User',
      icon: 'user',
    },
    {
      code: 'U01',
      permission_name: 'Create User',
      groupBy: 'User',
      icon: 'user',
    },
  
    {
      code: 'B00',
      permission_name: 'Read Batch',
      groupBy: 'Batch',
      icon: 'user',
    },
    {
      code: 'B01',
      permission_name: 'Create Batch',
      groupBy: 'Batch',
      icon: 'user',
    },
    {
      code: 'B10',
      permission_name: 'Update Batch',
      groupBy: 'Batch',
      icon: 'user',
    }
];
    
let results = permissions.reduce(function(accumulator, current) {
    let previousPermission = accumulator.find(function(el){
        return el.label === current.groupBy
    });
    
    if(!previousPermission){
        return accumulator.concat({
            label: current.groupBy, 
            icon: current.icon,
            children: [{
              label: current.permission_name  
            }]
        });
    } else {

        let permissionIndex = accumulator.findIndex(item => {
          return item.label === previousPermission.label;     
        });

        previousPermission = {
            ...previousPermission,
            children: [
              ...previousPermission.children,
              { label: current.permission_name }
            ]
        }
        accumulator[permissionIndex] = previousPermission;
        return accumulator;
    }
  
}, []);

console.log(results);
```